# How can I simulate correlated stock returns with a geometric brownian motion in R?

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo, portfolio

I'm trying to extend a code I already have. My goal is to simulate portfolio returns (log returns) of 5 correlated stocks with a geometric brownian motion by using historical drift and volatility. I used the code before to simulate the return of only one stock and it worked perfectly.

*Background:* I started with downloading stock prices of 5 companies (going 5 years in the past) from yahoo finance and extracted the closing price (so each stock price is only a column vector now, not a matrix). Then I transformed each of those 5 price vectors into vectors with log returns by using `returns.DAI = diff(log(price.DAI))` (that's only one example of the Daimler stock). Then I created a matrix to combine the 5 log return vectors (returns.matrix) and calculated the covariance matrix of the returns matrix. Afterwards I did a Cholesky decomposition of the covariance matrix with `chol.decomp=chol(cov.matrix)`. I also created a vector with the historical drifts (mu's) `mu.portfolio=rbind(mu.DAI,mu.ADS,mu.BAS,mu.FME,mu.HEI)`

**You might have to load some libraries with
library(quantmod);library(PerformanceAnalytics)**

Here's the full code now:

```
# download prices from yahoo for 5 stocks manually because there are
# mistakes in the data when you use getSymbols()!!!

# ALSO, unfortunately I had to sort the csv's in Excel because 
# when you download it from yahoo, it shows the newest price first. ^^
DAI=read.csv("LOCATION ON YOUR COMPUTER/NAME OF YOUR FILE.csv")
ADS=read.csv("LOCATION ON YOUR COMPUTER/NAME OF YOUR FILE.csv")
BAS=read.csv("LOCATION ON YOUR COMPUTER/NAME OF YOUR FILE.csv")
FME=read.csv("LOCATION ON YOUR COMPUTER/NAME OF YOUR FILE.csv")
HEI=read.csv("LOCATION ON YOUR COMPUTER/NAME OF YOUR FILE.csv")

# extracting close prices
price.DAI=DAI[,5]
price.ADS=ADS[,5]
price.BAS=BAS[,5]
price.FME=FME[,5]
price.HEI=HEI[,5]

# calculating log returns
returns.DAI = diff(log(price.DAI))
returns.ADS = diff(log(price.ADS))
returns.BAS = diff(log(price.BAS))
returns.FME = diff(log(price.FME))
returns.HEI = diff(log(price.HEI))

# matrix of returns
returns.matrix=cbind(returns.DAI,returns.ADS,returns.BAS,returns.FME,returns.HEI)

# calculate mu (drift)
mu.DAI=mean(returns.DAI)
mu.ADS=mean(returns.ADS)
mu.BAS=mean(returns.BAS)
mu.FME=mean(returns.FME)
mu.HEI=mean(returns.HEI)
mu.portfolio=rbind(mu.DAI,mu.ADS,mu.BAS,mu.FME,mu.HEI)

# calculate sigma
sigma.DAI=sd(returns.DAI)
sigma.ADS=sd(returns.ADS)
sigma.BAS=sd(returns.BAS)
sigma.FME=sd(returns.FME)
sigma.HEI=sd(returns.HEI)
sigma.pf=rbind(sigma.DAI,sigma.ADS,sigma.BAS,sigma.FME,sigma.HEI)

# covariance matrix
cov.matrix=cov(returns.matrix)

# Cholesky decomposition
chol.decomp=chol(cov.matrix)
```

Now, here's my already extended but defective function:

```
brownian.motion = function(number,dt,mu=c(0,0,0,0,0),sigma=cov.matrix){
  t=seq(from=0,to=number*dt,by=dt)
  n=length(t)
  # normally distributed gains
  dw=rnorm(n-1,mean=mu.portfolio*dt,sd=chol.decomp*sqrt(dt))
  # start in 0
  w=c(0,lapply(lapply(dw, cumsum), cumsum))
  return(w)
}

number=250       #DAX stocks are approximately traded on 250 days per year so that's a one year simulation.
dt=1/number      #delta (time steps)
sim=10000        #10000 simulations for each stock return
bm=matrix(nrow = number+1,ncol = sim)

for (i in 1:sim){
  bm[,i]=brownian.motion(number,dt,mu.portfolio,cov.matrix)
}
```

**When I run this code I get the following error:
"Error in bm[, i] = brownian.motion(number, dt, mu.portfolio, cov.matrix) : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"**

Could anyone please help me? I'm getting desperate because I tried so much and there's always another error. I'm not even a 100% sure if it's mathematically correct where I put the cholesky decomposition and covariance matrix.

Comment: If you want help you need to provide a reasonable amount of data for testing. We get: `object 'mu.portfolio`   not found. I suggest posting output from `dput(tail(mu.portfolio, 20))`

Comment: Ok, I just tried to break it down to the core problem but now I edited the question so you can see the full code.

Comment: I think another error just occured because I changed it for you to getSymbols(). Now the cholesky decomposition doesn't work anymore. It says "Error in chol.default(cov.matrix) : the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite"
But it always works when I download the data manually and import it with read.csv()
Yes, I just tested it. I'm going to edit it again.